# create specific XML file from XSD file with python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xsd

I have an existing xsd schema, and need to create (hopefully with Python) an XML file with some specific inputs.
What is the best way to do it? I tried Element Tree and xmlschema, but I cannot tell if these allow to generate XML files starting from a known XSD schema.
Thanks

Comment: Why are both of the answers bringing up JSON, when your question never mentioned it? I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3):

here is a minimal working example with json data

```
import xmlschema
import json
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

my_xsd = '<?xml version="1.0"?> <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string"/> </xs:schema>'

schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema(my_xsd)
data = json.dumps({'note': 'this is a Note text'})

xml = xmlschema.from_json(data, schema=schema, preserve_root=True)

ElementTree(xml).write('my_xml.xml')
```

for more complex xsd's I prefer working with generateDS, which creates very very solid classes from even for very large xsd files.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I did the following and seems to do the job:

```
import xmlschema
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
# create XML from json, starting from known schema file 
sch      = 'schema_file.xsd'
schema   = xmlschema.XMLSchema(sch) 
jsondata = json of the data to be converted to XML
xml      = xmlschema.from_json(jsondata,schema=schema)
# write to XML
ElementTree(xml).write('myxml.xml')
```

Comment: How do you know what the JSON data has to look like? That's where I'm currently tripping.

Comment: The [xmlschema documentation on decoding the schema to JSON](https://xmlschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#decoding-to-json) should give you an idea of how the JSON would look like.