# Is there a way to add elements in an XML DOM based on XSD schema using Python?

Tags: python, xml, xsd

Is there a way to create an XML file using XSD schema in python?

I already have an XSD file. When creating an XML file, I want to automatically add elements in the right order and place using the XSD schema. There are libraries to validate already created schema but I haven't come across anything that could help dynamically add elements in the XML file without having to manually specify their place based on an XSD schema.

Answer (score 0):

[create specific XML file from XSD file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283389/create-specific-xml-file-from-xsd-file-with-python)
and
[xmlschema](https://github.com/sissaschool/xmlschema)